# Completion of a linear order that is a dense subspace of a compact space.

Tags: general-topology, order-theory, uniform-spaces

Suppose $D$ is a linearly ordered space which is densely embedded in a compact Hausdorff space $K$.

What can we say about the relation between $K$ and $\overline D$, the completion of $D$. Is one a subspace of the other? Could we add other properties to $K$ to simplify the matter, or to even make $K $ homeomorphic to $\overline D$ ?

EDIT: I think I should clarify a few things.

- By "completion of $D$,"  $\overline D$, I mean the Dedekind completion of $D$ with the order topology.
- I want to know about the relation between the topological spaces $\overline D$ and $K$, assuming (i) $D$ is a dense subset of $K$, and (ii) The order topology on $D$ is the same as the topology $D$ inherits as a subspace of $K$.

Comment: Is $K$ compact Hausdorff or just compact? To extend the embedding to the completion of $D$ is has to be a map into a complete Hausdorff space, so $K$ should be Hausdorff. Then it has a unique uniform structure and is complete as a uniform space.

Comment: Assume $X=\{a,b\}$ with topology $\{\emptyset,\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$. Let $D=\{a\}$ with its trivial order. Then $D$ is dense in $X$ and already complete, but not equal to $X$. Oh, well, alternatively the question above.

Comment: Yes to Hausdorff.

Comment: We can take the rational numbers in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and embed them, densely, both in $[-1,1]$ and in the unit circle. The completion is always going to be $(-\pi,\pi)$, isn't it?

Comment: The closure $\text{cl}D$ is a compact subspace of $K$. Since $K$ is compact Hausdorff, there is a unique uniform structure $\mathcal U$ which induces the given topology on $K$. But compact uniform spaces are complete, so $\text{cl}D$ is complete. Furthermore, each uniformly continuous map $f:D\to Y$ to a complete Hausdorff space $Y$ can be uniquely extended to a uniformly continuous map $\tilde f:\text{cl}D\to Y$, which implies that $\text{cl}D$ is just the Hausdorff completion of $D$.

Comment: What do you mean by cl$D$ ? In my notation this $is$ the completion of $D$, whereas the closure of $D$ in $K$ is simply $K$.

Comment: Whoops! I forgot that $D$ is dense in $K$. So $K$ itself is the Hausdorff completion of $D$.

Comment: @David: Please check if what I wrote makes sense and I understood you correctly. Also note that I considered $D$ a subspace of $K$, which only works if $\phi$ is a bijection $D\to\phi(D)$ which is uniformly continuous in both directions. I my comment answers your question, let me know and I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Yes we can have an embedding $\varphi:D\to K$, which is the same thing as saying $D$ is a subspace of $K$. I am interested in your answer.  I assume by "Hausdorff completion" you mean the the Dedekind completion of $D$ with the linear order topology?

Comment: Do not forget to use `@Stefan` in your comment, so I get notified about your comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without additional hypotheses it need not be the case that $\overline D$ embeds in $K$.

$\Bbb N$ with its usual order and order topology is a LOTS that is densely embedded in the compact Hausdorff space $\beta\Bbb N$. The Dedekind completion $\overline{\Bbb N}$ of $\Bbb N$ is $\Bbb N\cup\{\infty\}$, where $n<\infty$ for each $n\in\Bbb N$, and the order topology makes this the one-point compactification of $\Bbb N$. However, $\beta\Bbb N$ contains no subspace homeomorphic to $\overline{\Bbb N}$: every infinite closed subset of $\beta\Bbb N$ contains a copy of $\beta\Bbb N$. (See, for instance, Theorem $3.6.14$ of Engelking, *General Topology*.)

**Added:** Let $D=\Bbb Q\cap(-1,1)$, so that $\overline{D}=[-1,1]$. Let $\tau$ be the usual topology on $[-1,1]$. Define

$$f:[-1,1]\to[-1,1]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }x\in D\\
-x,&\text{if }x\notin D\;.
\end{cases}$$

Let $\tau'=\{f[U]:U\in\tau\}$; $f$ is a bijection, so it’s easy to check that $\tau'$ is a topology on $[-1,1]$ and indeed that $\big\langle[-1,1],\tau'\big\rangle$ is homeomorphic to $\big\langle[-1,1],\tau'\big\rangle$ and has $D$ as a dense subset. However, $\tau\nsubseteq\tau'\nsubseteq\tau$.

**Added<sub>2</sub>:** Let $A=\{2^{-n}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\}$, and let $D=[0,1]\setminus A$ with the usual order; clearly $\overline{D}=[0,1]$. Let $X=\big([0,1]\times\{0\}\big)\cup\big(A\times\{1\}\big)$, ordered lexicographically; it’s not hard to check that $X$ is compact, and that $D\times\{0\}$ is dense in $X$ and homeomorphic to $D$. Note that $X$ is not connected; e.g., $\left\{\left\langle\frac12,1\right\rangle\right\}\cup\left(\left(\frac12,1\right]\times\{0\}\right)$ is a clopen subset of $X$, so $X$ is not homeomorphic to $\overline{D}$. (In fact $X$ is homeomorphic to the one-point compactification of $[0,1]\times\omega$.) Let

$$f:[0,1]\to X:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
\langle x,0\rangle,&\text{if }x\in D\\
\langle 2^{-n},0\rangle,&\text{if }x=2^{-2n}\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\\
\langle 2^{-n},1\rangle,&\text{if }x=2^{-(2n-1)}\text{ for some }n\in\Bbb Z^+\;.
\end{cases}$$

clearly $f$ is a bijection. Let $\tau=\{f^{-1}[U]:U\text{ is open in }X\}$; then $\tau$ is a topology on $[0,1]$. Denote $\big\langle[0,1],\tau\big\rangle$ by $K$; $K$ is homeomorphic to $X$, and $D$ has the same relative topology in $K$ as in $[0,1]$ with its usual topology, but $K$ and $[0,1]$ are not homeomorphic. Moreover, if $\mathscr{E}$ is the Euclidean topology on $[0,1]$, then

$$\left\{\frac14\right\}\cup\left(\frac38,\frac12\right)\in\tau\setminus\mathscr{E}\;,$$

and

$$\left(\frac3{16},\frac38\right)\in\mathscr{E}\setminus\tau\;,$$

so $\mathscr{E}$ and $\tau$ are not comparable in the lattice of topologies on $[0,1]$.

Comment: What if $K$ and $\overline D$ have the same underlying sets?  Are they then homeomorphic, or at least is one topology finer than the other?

Comment: @David: The topologies need not be comparable even if the spaces are homeomorphic. I’ll have to think further about whether they must be homeomorphic.

Comment: @David: I’ve added an example showing that $K$ and $\overline{D}$ need not be homeomorphic even if they have the same underlying set.

Comment: Thanks for the new example.  For the specific spaces I'm interested in, I have found that if $D\subseteq K$ and $E\subseteq L$ are linear orders dense in compact spaces $K$,$L$ resp., then an isomorphism between their completions induces a homeomorphism between $K$ and $L$.  This is really what I wanted to prove, even though its not so simple as: $\overline E \simeq L$, $\overline D \simeq K$, and $\overline D \approx \overline E$ $\implies$ $K\simeq L$.

Comment: @David: You’re welcome. It was an interesting problem.

Comment: I am still looking through "Added2" but maybe later I will share my example where something nice happens.